# How can i assign a value in a list to a group of values in my data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data of 10 values that I would like to assign them according to its percentage.

My data:

```
    stock    value

    s_001   -0.001932
    s_002    0.004001
    s_003    0.001323
    s_004   -0.006785
    s_005    0.004405
    s_006   -0.002872
    s_007    0.003101
    s_008    0.001383
    s_009   -0.004785
    s_010    0.001405
```

Percentiles:

```
    breakpoints = [0, 20, 40, 60, 80]
```

I used df.sort_values to sort the values according to chronological order:

```
    stock    value

    s_001   -0.001932        
    s_006   -0.002872
    s_009   -0.004785
    s_004   -0.006785
    s_003    0.001323
    s_008    0.001383
    s_010    0.001405
    s_007    0.003101
    s_002    0.004001
    s_005    0.004405
```

After sorting, how can I assign the first two values to the first percentile, then the next two to the second percentile and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html). You will need the breakpoints as numbers between 0 and 1:

```
breakpoints = [0. , 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]
df['quantile'] = pd.qcut(df['value'],
                         breakpoints+[1],
                         labels=[int(i*100) for i in breakpoints]
                         )
```

*NB. the dataframe needs not to be sorted for this*

output:

```
   stock     value quantile
0  s_001 -0.001932       20
1  s_002  0.004001       80
2  s_003  0.001323       40
3  s_004 -0.006785        0
4  s_005  0.004405       80
5  s_006 -0.002872       20
6  s_007  0.003101       60
7  s_008  0.001383       40
8  s_009 -0.004785        0
9  s_010  0.001405       60
```

Comment: No, pandas.cut uses the actual values, not the quantiles ;)